# laravel search multiple words separated by space

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, query-builder

I am new to laravel query builder, I want to search multiple words entered in an input field for example if I type "jhon doe" I want to get any column that contains jhon or doe

I have seen/tried solutions using php MySQL but can't able to adapt to query builder

```
//1. exploding the space between the keywords 

//2. using foreach apend the query together

$query = "select * from users where";

$keywordRaw = "jhon doe";
$keywords = explode(' ', $keywordRaw );
foreach ($keywords as $keyword){
$query.= " first_name LIKE '%" + $keyword +"%' OR ";
}
```

how do I do this using query builder

this is what i have so far, what is the proper way of doing this,

```
$keywordRaw = "jhon doe";
//how do I explode this words and append them along with their appropriate query
$users = User::select('users.*')
->where('first_name', 'LIKE', '%'.$keywordRaw.'%')
```

please help, thanks in advance

Answer (score 53, accepted):

This is how you do it with `Query\Builder`, but first some additional notes:

```
// user can provide double space by accident, or on purpose:
$string = 'john  doe';

// so with explode you get this:
explode(' ', $string);
array(
  0 => 'john',
  1 => '',
  2 => 'doe'
)

// Now if you go with LIKE '%'.value.'%', you get this:
select * from table where name like '%john%' or name like '%%' or ...
```

That said, you obviously can't rely on `explode` because in the above case you would get all the rows.

So, this is what you should do:

```
$string = 'john  doe';

// split on 1+ whitespace & ignore empty (eg. trailing space)
$searchValues = preg_split('/\s+/', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY); 

$users = User::where(function ($q) use ($searchValues) {
  foreach ($searchValues as $value) {
    $q->orWhere('name', 'like', "%{$value}%");
  }
})->get();
```

There is closure in the `where` because it is a good practice to wrap your `or where` clauses in parentheses. For example if your `User` model used `SoftDeletingScope` and you would not do what I suggested, your whole query would be messed up.

Comment: thanks @Jarek, I just implemented it with my other joined tables, paginate it, and works perfectly, thanks again

Answer (score 3):

```
 $keywordRaw = "jhon doe";
    $key = explode(' ',$keywordRaw);
    $users = User::select('users.*')
    ->whereIn('first_name',$key);
```

This would work.the whereIn would search for first name from the keywords you entered.

Comment: `whereIn` is explicit, ie `=`, while OP wants `like %value%`, so it's not the one. Also double space or another whitespace in the string makes it invalid.

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered using a FULLTEXT index on your first_name column?

You can create this index using a Laravel migration, although you need to use an SQL statement:

```
DB::statement('ALTER TABLE users ADD FULLTEXT(first_name);');
```

You can then run quite advanced searches against this field, like this:

```
$keywordRaw = "john doe";
$keywords   = explode(' ', $keywordRaw);
$users   = User::select("*")
              ->whereRaw("MATCH (first_name)
                          against (? in boolean mode)",[$keywords])
              ->get();
```

That will match records containing either the words "john" or "doe"; note that this approach will match on whole words, rather than substrings (which can be the case if you use LIKE).

If you want to find records containing *all* words, you should precede each keyword with a '+', like this:

```
$keywords   = '+'.explode(' +', $keywordRaw);
```

You can even sort by relevance, although this is probably overkill for your needs (and irrelevant for "all" searches). Something like this:

```
$users = User::select("*")
               ->selectRaw("MATCH (first_name)
                            against (? in boolean mode)
                            AS relevance",[$keywords])
               ->whereRaw("MATCH (first_name)
                           against (? in boolean mode)",[$keywords])
               ->orderBy('relevance','DESC')
               ->get();
```

There is a good article that covers this general approach here:

http://www.hackingwithphp.com/9/3/18/advanced-text-searching-using-full-text-indexes

Answer (score 2):

**You can try as follows**

```
$keywordRaw = "jhon doe";
$bindArr = explode(" ", $keywordRaw);

$query = "select * from users where";    
foreach ($i = 0; $i < count($bindArr); $i++) {
    if ($i == 0) {
        $query.= ' first_name LIKE "%?%"';
    } else {        
        $query.= ' or first_name LIKE "%?%"';
    }
}

$sth = $dbh->prepare($query);
$sth->execute($bindArr);
```

Answer (score 2):

**Try this..**

```
   $searchQuery = "jhon doe"; 
$searchTerms = explode(" ", $searchQuery); // Split the words
$users = User::whereIn('FirstName', $searchTerms)->get();
print_r($users);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = 'john  doe';

// split on 1+ whitespace & ignore empty (eg. trailing space)
$searchValues = preg_split('/\s+/', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY); 

$users = User::where(function ($q) use ($searchValues) {
  foreach ($searchValues as $value) {
    $q->Where('name', 'like', "%{$value}%");
  }
})->get();
```

Using 'orWhere' will get you results for each keyword not results for keyword1 + keyword2...So all depends on what your looking for

Answer (score 0):

You can use this package https://github.com/nicolaslopezj/searchable

or just do this, if you don't want to use package

```
$keywordRaw = "jhon doe";
$users = User::where('first_name', 'LIKE', $keywordRaw.'%')
->orWhere('first_name', 'LIKE', '% '.$keywordRaw.'%')
->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a first solution below and it worked

**Solution 1**

```
function fuzzySearch($keyword='jhon doe'){
   $queryText = implode('%',str_split($keyWord));
   return User::query()->where('first_name','LIKE',"%{$queryText}%")->get();
}
```

However, when i added spaces in my search it returns empty results yet they exist in the database so I added `str_replace(" ","",$keyWord)` to remove whitespace and now it works

**Solution 2**

```
function fuzzySearch($keyword='jhon doe'){
   $queryText = implode('%',str_split(str_replace(" ","",$keyWord)));
   return User::query()->where('first_name','LIKE',"%{$queryText}%")->get();
}
```

**NOTE** `implode()` function converts the keyword **jhon doe** to `j%h%o%n%d%o%e`